# Passing a value from a dropdown list in a fragment to another activity (Kotlin)

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-fragments, android-activity

I am making an app (ehealth portal) in Android Studio using Kotlin language and in that app, the user should be able to book an appointment choosing date/time/doctor's name from a dropdown list, and once they push the "book a date" button a confirmation screen appears that has the values of the dropdown lists (date/time/doctor's name) passed into a confirmation text [confirmation activity instance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/42AVY.jpg) [booking a dated interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pqrWL.jpg).

### CalendarFragment.kt

```
 package com.example.mydoctor
    
    import...
    
    
    class CalendarFragment : Fragment() {
    
        private lateinit var binding: FragmentCalendarBinding1
    
        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    
            setHasOptionsMenu(true)
        }
    
        override fun onCreateView(
            inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
            savedInstanceState: Bundle?
        ): View? {
    
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            binding = FragmentCalendarBinding1.inflate(layoutInflater)
    
            val itemsDates = resources.getStringArray(R.array.dates)
            val adapterDate = ArrayAdapter(requireContext(), list_dates, itemsDates)
            binding.autocompleteTextViewDateDropdown.setAdapter(adapterDate)
    
            val itemsTimes = resources.getStringArray(R.array.times)
            val adapterTime = ArrayAdapter(requireContext(), list_times, itemsTimes)
            binding.autocompleteTextViewTimeDropdown.setAdapter(adapterTime)
    
            binding.bookADateButton.setOnClickListener {
                val intent = Intent(requireContext(),ConfirmationActivity::class.java)
                intent.putExtra("Confirmation","Confirmation Value")
                startActivity(intent)
            }
    
            return binding.root
    
        }


}
```

### ConfirmationActivity.kt

package com.example.mydoctor

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log

class ConfirmationActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
setContentView(R.layout.activity_confirmation)

```
    val value = intent.getStringExtra("Confirmation").toString()
    Log.d("conf","Values is: ${value}")
}
```

}

How can I go about that? I know I have to use getExtra()  or getStringExtra() but how should I actually get the value from the calendar fragment?

**EDIT:**

I tried changing the `setOnClickListener` in the CalendarFragment.kt as follows but it does not seem to work storing the value:

```
 binding.bookADateButton.setOnClickListener {

            (date_dropdown.getEditText() as AutoCompleteTextView).onItemClickListener =
            OnItemClickListener {
                    adapterView, view, position, _ ->
                    val selectedValue: String? = adapterDate.getItem(position)
                
                }

            val intent = Intent(requireContext(),ConfirmationActivity::class.java)
            intent.putExtra("Confirmation","Confirmation Value")
            startActivity(intent)
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to setup your date_dropdown listener outside of the setOnClickListener, otherwise you only start listening to date_dropdown changes after the first click is made, which is already too late.

So change the order in your code

```kotlin
// have a variable to track the last selected value with a larger
// scope somewhere inside your Fragment
var selectedValue: String? = null

(date_dropdown.getEditText() as AutoCompleteTextView).onItemClickListener =
  OnItemClickListener { adapterView, view, position, _ ->
    // this code block is called every time an item is clicked
    selectedValue = adapterDate.getItem(position)
}

binding.bookADateButton.setOnClickListener {
    // this code block is called every time the 'bookADateButton' is clicked       
    val intent = Intent(requireContext(), ConfirmationActivity::class.java)
    intent.putExtra("Confirmation", selectedValue ?: "No value was selected.")
    startActivity(intent)
}
```

There is also the [setOnItemSelectedListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView#setOnItemSelectedListener(android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener)) available, if you don't want to rely on clicks/taps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The problem now is that as soon as I try to access my CalendarFragment from bottom Nav it shoots me back to the login screen without accessing it.

Comment: @DimitrisSidiropoulos Have you used onItemClickListener or setOnItemSelectedListener then? Place breakpoints in various parts of the code and instead of "Run" press "Debug". The execution will stop at breakpoints and in this way you can see what is going on and where it is going wrong. Since I don't know how your app navigation is wired up, I can't really say anything about why it would navigate back to the login screen. What exactly happens in your app, if you use your old code, the previous order (the one from your edited question)?

Comment: I have sold the issue thanks :) I was not using putExtra properly and then getStringExtra at the confirmation.